# An accesible directory on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, qt

I am developing Qt based iOS application. Currently I am trying to save a file from within the application in a place, where I will be able to access it from other applications, such as file explorers. At first I used:

```
QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DownloadLocation);
```

just for testing purposes. I was surprised that the path obtained was:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4FDF6B25-8197-469B-ADE7-A1A1FD181D0F/Documents/Downloads/
```

I have no possibility to access this location from another app.
The iOS file exploring capability is quite limited. Is there any real way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Does putting them onto iCloud fits your usecase?

Comment: Not really. I just need to save a configuration file in a place, where I can manually edit it using any text editor.

Answer (score 0):

From your iOS app you can only see the files in that app, not others. This is the way iOS OS was build for security reasons.

Might be done maybe on Jailbroken devices

Answer (score 0):

There is nowhere within your app's own file structure that is accessible to other apps due to iOS sandboxing.

You can use [`UIDocumentPickerViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller) to export a file from your app directly to a file provider location such as iCloud, OneDrive, Dropbox or any other file provider that the user has installed on their device.